# Identify a lug framed BMX probably from 70s

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

can anyone identify my old lug-framed BMX? It is very much like a Scorpion SX but with one difference.

[image]

Comment: Gonna need more pictures.

Comment: And please crop the unneeded white space from your photos. Just upload the photos themselves, not screenshots of a screen showing a photo.

Comment: That seat clamp area looks distinctive - the angle is unusual.  What words or logos are written anywhere on the frame ?